# How to mock/replace getter function of object with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, sinon, jestjs

In Sinon I can do the following:

```
var myObj = {
    prop: 'foo'
};

sinon.stub(myObj, 'prop').get(function getterFn() {
    return 'bar';
});

myObj.prop; // 'bar'
```

But how can I do the same with Jest?
I can't just overwrite the function with something like `jest.fn()`, because it won't replace the getter

> "can't set the value of get"

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You could use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'prop', {
  get: jest.fn(() => 'bar'),
  set: jest.fn()
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, that works. Sometimes I notice I don't need more knowledge about some library/framework but the fundamental workings of JavaScript.

May I ask one follow up question:
How would I mock this function if I wanted my mock to replace the original function just one time but the next call should handled by the original function again?

Comment: This works, but when I try to do it in my beforeEach() call it fails with `Cannot redefine property`. Why is this?

Comment: @clu add `configurable: true` to your the `defineProperty` function. That should do the trick

Comment: Notice that - in contrast with mocks - it won't "unmock" your getter at the end of each test case, so - if other tests rely on the original return value of the getter - you may get different results running one test and the whole suite.

Comment: getting cannot redefine property.

Comment: Scroll down to Franey answer. It is more recent.

Comment: This is really good as this allows working with the complex object's fixture - its POJO representation. This especially useful when you have to supply that object as dependency and would not like to bother creating the actual object - actually keeping yourself away from integration tesing when it is not yet desirable.

Answer (score 193):

For anyone else stumbling across this answer, Jest 22.1.0 introduced the ability to [spy on getter and setter methods](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype).

Edit: like in [scieslak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54346703/3930128) below, because you can spy on getter and setter methods, you can use Jest mocks with them, just like with any other function:

```
class MyClass {
  get something() {
    return 'foo'
  }
}

jest.spyOn(MyClass.prototype, 'something', 'get').mockReturnValue('bar')
const something = new MyClass().something

expect(something).toEqual('bar')
```

Comment: @taystack Being able to spy on the getters/setters was a necessary step toward being able to mock them like a regular function. I updated my answer to be more explicit about that and added a mock to the example code.

Comment: **`something property does not exist`** with `jest@24.9.0`with `["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"`, while [it works fine with scieslak solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54346703/7295772) which sets the spy exactly on the `awesomeness` instance. In `rspec` I would use a method called `any_instance` and I would mock/stub `any_instance` of that class. There is a clear difference in syntax between the [jest official `spyOn` documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype) and your example. In that example jest spys on an object literal

Comment: `const video = { get play() { return true; },};`

Comment: @fabrizo jest.spyOn(MyClass, 'something', 'get').mockReturnValue('bar')
should be jest.spyOn(MyClass.prototype, 'something', 'get').mockReturnValue('bar')

Comment: I Second @Mike P., you need to use the `prototype` for it to work

Answer (score 23):

If you care about spying only, go for @Franey 's answer. However if you actually need to stub a value for the getter, this is how you can do it:

```js
class Awesomeness {
  get isAwesome() {
    return true
  }
}

describe('Awesomeness', () => {
  it('is not always awesome', () => {
    const awesomeness = new Awesomeness
    jest.spyOn(awesomeness, 'isAwesome', 'get').mockReturnValue(false)

    expect(awesomeness.isAwesome).toEqual(false)
  })
})
```

Comment: I got an error that the property does not exist. It also looks like the other answer calls `spyOn` on the class whereas you call it on an instance.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing - 'property does not exist' - when calling on an instance.

Answer (score 2):

In my unity test case, as it is expected to mock external dependencies, following the thomaux's answer, i had to use a real instance instead of a mocked one in beforeEach function, see the snippet bellow.

```
//declaration of MyExternalConfigService with getter
@Injectable()
export class MyExternalConfigService {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}
  get myProp():string {
    return this.configService.get<string>('context.myProp')
  }
}

//beforeEach unit test configuration
beforeEach(async () => {
  const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
      MyServiceToBeTested,
      {
       provide: MyExternalConfigService,
        useValue: new MyExternalConfigService(new ConfigService())
      }        
    ]
  }).compile()

  service = module.get<MyServiceToBeTested>(
    MyServiceToBeTested
  )
  configService = module.get<MyExternalConfigService>MyExternalConfigService)

})

//mocking a value to your test case
it('my test case', ()=>{
  jest
    .spyOn(configService, 'myProp', 'get')
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => 'mockedValue')
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Jest v29.5 you can use [jest.replaceProperty](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestreplacepropertyobject-propertykey-value) like this:

```
var myObj = {
    prop: 'foo'
};

jest.replaceProperty(myObj, 'prop', 'bar')

myObj.prop; // 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use @Franey's [answer with spyOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43697455/how-to-mock-replace-getter-function-of-object-with-jest/49455429#49455429), but if you are mocking the the whole module you can just set it as a normal parameter:

```js
class MyClass {
  get something() {
    return 'foo'
  }
}

// With this here, you are ignoring the whole class, so the property will be set by whatever you set
jest.mock('./MyClass');

test('something', () => {
  MyClass.prototype.something = 'bar'
  const something = new MyClass().something

  expect(something).toEqual('bar')
})
```

This is useful for some specific cases, but I thought it was worth mentioning.