# Runtime error in jest - TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a typescript file defined like so:

```
// myType.tsx

import { Foo } from 'foo';
[...]
export interface MyType extends IDisposable {
[...]
}

export abstract class MyTypeBase implements MyType {
  innerFoo: Foo | null | undefined;
  get foo(): Foo {
    return this.innerFoo;
  }

  [...]
}
```

I am trying to test another class which depends on this `MyType`, and I want to mock out the `foo()` getter.

In my test file, once I add the following to the file:

```
[...]
import { MyType } from 'path/to/MyType';
[...]
jest.mock('path/to/MyType', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {foo: () => mockFoo}; //mockFoo is defined earlier in the file.
  })
});
```

I get an error when running the test:
`Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null`

This only occurs when I include the `jest.mock(...)` line.

From other questions related, I see this can be caused by circular dependencies, but I'm failing to see how that can introduced by a call to `jest.mock`? I can see that other breakpoints that are hit when I comment out this code are not being hit, so it appears as though adding this mock is causing my test to fail early for this reason.

Anyone come across this before?

Comment: Based on my breakpoints that are bound (or not), it appears as though something is going wrong in the class `MySubType extends MyTypeBase`, as calling the constructor to `MySubType` is failing, and there are also no breakpoints binding within that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is explained in [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter):

> A limitation with the factory parameter is that, since calls to jest.mock() are hoisted to the top of the file, it's not possible to first define a variable and then use it in the factory. An exception is made for variables that start with the word 'mock'. It's up to you to guarantee that they will be initialized on time! For example, the following will throw an out-of-scope error due to the use of 'fake' instead of 'mock' in the variable declaration

The use of `mockFoo` variable name allows to use it inside `jest.mock` factory function at your own risk.

> mockFoo is defined earlier in the file

This is not true as `jest.mock` hoisted above respective import but a variable it refers is not defined at the time when mocked module is evaluated. For eagerly evaluated mocked modules a mock needs to be defined inside a factory. In case it needs to be accessed in a test, it can be exposed via a module.

`foo` is property accessor but is mocked as a function.

Also mocked module is CommonJS, this will prevent named imports from being correctly mapped in most setups, there should be `__esModule: true` in mocked module.

Comment: > This is not true as jest.mock hoisted above respective import but a variable it refers is not defined at the time when mocked module is evaluated --

My understanding from the piece of documentation you quoted is taht since the variable name is prefixed with `mock-` that it can get initialized before the `jest.mock` call, no?

Comment: The key issue that caused this error was the way in which I was mocking the property, as you pointed out, property accessors are mocked differently to functions. This question with Mike P.'s addition solved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/49455429/1031682

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. No, `mock` prefix means that you disable a fool proof. It says, *It's up to you to guarantee that they will be initialized on time*. You cannot guarantee that with local variables because ES module `import` goes above everything else by specs.